# Need clarification on boost::optional type

Tags: c++, boost-optional

I’m trying to make sense out of a few details obtained from the core file with respect to boost::optional type variable.

Variable:

```
boost::optional<Cacher> cacher_;
```

Frame #5 from the core:

```
(gdb) p this->cacher_
$1 = boost::optional
```

The line being executed in this frame is:

```
cacher_ = boost::none;
```

As a result, a few frames leading upto to the crash, point to boost library code:

```
#1  0x000000000152f96c in destroy_impl (this=0x32557590) at /opt/include/boost/optional/optional.hpp:479
#2  destroy (this=0x32557590) at /opt/include/boost/optional/optional.hpp:439
#3  assign (this=0x32557590) at /opt/include/boost/optional/optional.hpp:313
#4  operator= (none_=NULL, this=0x32557590) at /opt/include/boost/optional/optional.hpp:615
```

Frame #0 is where the destructor of `Cacher` is called, and the crash is because the memory held by the object has already been freed.

My question:

1. Does `boost::optional` indicate that the memory held by `cacher_` is valid?
2. As a result of assigning `boost::none` to `cacher_`, would the object be destroyed?

Apologies if the details to diagnose the problem are insufficient. I’ll try to provide additional details based on the responses.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) keeps track of whether it holds a valid object. This can be checked by using `operator bool()` or `is_initialized()`.

If you assign `boost::none` (or call `.reset()`) it will properly destroy the object it holds, if any.

The same holds true for [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) (except for `boost::none` assignment, to the best of my knowledge).

Comment: `(gdb) frame 3
#3  assign (this=0x32557590) at /opt/ include/boost/optional/optional.hpp:313
313         void assign ( none_t ) { destroy(); }
(gdb) p *this
$9 = {<boost::optional_detail::optional_tag> = {<No data fields>}, m_initialized = false, m_storage = {dummy_ = {
      data = “………………………………….", aligner_ = {<No data fields>}}}}` 
Does `m_initialized = false` indicate that the object is not valid?

Comment: I don't think *valid* is a correct term. The optional is empty, there's no object stored in it. Kind of like empty `unique_ptr` (optional is very much like a smart pointer, but we use it for clarity).

Comment: Ok. In the present case, what are we trying to destroy when there's no object? In any case, is it correct to assign `boost::none` without checking for whether `cacher_` is initialized or not?

Comment: If there is no object nothing is supposed to be destroyed. It's safe to assign `boost::none` to such an optional but it should leave it in identical state (like assigning `nullptr` to already empty `unique_ptr`)

Comment: Isn't the destructor called on an object? What am I missing in the present case?

Comment: I'm not sure, to be honest. It's possible that your program was broken before, i.e. by stack smashing, and that's why you're seeing garbage. In a correct situation, optional won't call a destructor on non-object,